# Number Pattern Interruption

Tags: java, numbers

I trying to figure out why this bit of code won't display anything after 8.

```
        public class numGame  
   {
        public static void main(String[] args)

        {
            int number1 = 3;
            int number2 = 8;
            int total = 0;

            System.out.print(number1 + " ");
            System.out.print(number2 + " ");


            while (total <450)
{
                total = number1 + number2;



            System.out.print(total + " ");



            number1 = number2;
            number2 = total;



          }

        }
    }
```

The idea is to have 3 and 8 added up to 11 then 19 then 30 then 49 and so on till it hits a number greater than or equal to 450 and end.

3, 8, 11, 19, 30, 49......

Is something wrong with the way its structured or something else?

[Update]

With the feedback from Luiggi, the code runs expect for one issue.

This output is : 3,8, 11, 19, 30, 49, 79, 128, 207, 335, 542

The program should cut off at 335, because 542 is over 450.

Would a if statement be one way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This would not even compile

a) sum is not defined

b) you print out total, but this has only ever been set to 0

c) neither num1 or num2 are incremented so sum is always going to be the same value (endless while loop)

d) num1 or num2 are not defined

e) why change values of number1 and number2 at the end?

try

```
while (total < 450) {
    total = number1 + number2;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calculating total anywhere.

Sum and Total are confusing.

Also num1 and number1 confusing.

While loop should have curly brackets.